# Why HttpServerUtility class is not supported in .Net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility?view=netframework-4.8
As mentioned in the preceding link, the HttpServerUtility class is only supported in .NetFramework.

System.Web namespace contains HttpServerUtility, but System.Web is supported in dotnet core, why HttpServerUtility not ?

Answer (score 3):

For .NET Core and .NET 5+ Must use the [HttpUtility Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility?view=net-6.0) Instead of [HttpServerUtility class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility?view=netframework-4.8.1)

Comment: In this link it is mentioned that "The HttpUtility class is used internally by the HttpServerUtility class" but HttpServerUtility class in not supported in .Net Core

Comment: I also did not say that it is supported in .net core. I said use `HttpUtility` instead of `HttpServerUtility` . It would be better to say what feature you need from the `HttpServerUtility` class, because features like `UrlEncode(String)` and ...  are available in the `HttpUtility` class